# Parse function call string into name and arguments

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a regular expression to parse a string that represents a function call.  I want to parse:

`createNewEmail(mailToJohn, recipientGeorge, Subject, content);`

into an array of strings:
`createNewMail`,
`mailToJohn`,
`recipientGeorge`,
`Subject`,
`content`

Other possible inputs could be:

`createNewEmail(mailToJohn, recipientGeorge, Subject, content);`

`makeTemplateUser(templateName, userName);`

`deleteEmail(emailToDelete);`

`updateUserSetting(userId, changedSettings, oldSettingsId);`

How do you suggest I parse this?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm finding this question really hard to understand.  I think you might need to take out all the detail about *why* you're doing this and focus on *what* you're trying to do. There's a lot of detail here that seems to rely on other details of your code that you haven't included.  I also don't think the 'regex' tag is appropriate unless you actually have a regex you need fixing.

Comment: This is still very confusing - try putting code (yes, even pseudocode) in actual code tags to improve readability. =)

Comment: @Carl Palsson I recently attempted to answer your recently deleted question; but as it was deleted, I was unable to do so. If you'd like to know my answer about dynamically calling a method like this, create a new question and let me know. Although, I will mention now that this path is fraught with peril. I spent a good deal of an hour writing it, so I'd appreciate being able to post it somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is really that simple, you can just use

```
line.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', '(', ')', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(s => s.Length > 1).ToArray();
```

It will work as long as none of your identifiers (function name or argument) are a single character long; if you need to handle that case just modify the `Where` filter.  This will return an array that you can just insert into your larger array (or add to a list, etc).